stacked barplot with repel legend manipulate single labels e.g. in italics
So I would like to manipulate some labels I have added to a stacked bar plot through repel. The problem is, that some names will have to be in italics, while others don't so I am trying to specify each and I can not succeed so far.
I previously created this plot with the normal legend where it worked:
predictions <- predictions %>%
  mutate(formatted_species = factor(
    response.level,
    levels = sort(unique(response.level))  # Sort species alphabetically
  ))

# manipulate labels
species_labels <- c(
  "Eledone.cirrhosa" = expression(italic("E. cirrhosa")),       # Italics
  "Argentina.sp." = expression(italic("Argentina sp.")),         # Italics
  "Gadidae.UKN" = "Gadidae UKN",                                 # Regular text
  "Gobiidae.UKN" = "Gobiidae UKN",                               # Regular text
  "Fish.UKN" = "Fish UKN",                                       # Regular text
  "Loligo.sp." = expression(italic("Loligo sp.")),              # Italics
  "M. merlangus" = expression(italic("M. merlangus")),           # Italics
  "M. poutassou" = expression(italic("M. poutassou")),           # Italics
  "M. aeglefinus" = expression(italic("M. aeglefinus")),         # Italics
  "Merluccius.merluccius" = expression(italic("M. merluccius")), # Italics
  "Clupea.harengus" = expression(italic("C. harengus")),         # Italics
  "Alloteuthis.sp." = expression(italic("Alloteuthis sp.")),     # Italics
  "Sepiolidae.UKN" = "Sepiolidae UKN",                           # Regular text
  "Sprattus.sprattus" = expression(italic("S. sprattus")),       # Italics
  "T. trachurus" = expression(italic("T. trachurus")),           # Italics
  "T. esmarkii" = expression(italic("T. esmarkii")),             # Italics
  "Teuthida.UKN" = "Teuthida UKN",                               # Regular text
  "Todaropsis.eblanae" = expression(italic("T. eblanae")),      # Italics
  "Trisopterus.sp." = expression(italic("Trisopterus sp.")),    # Italics
  "Trisopterus.esmarkii" = expression(italic("T. esmarkii")),    # Italics
  "Merlangius.merlangus" = expression(italic("M. merlangus"))     # Italics
)
#plot
g <- ggplot(predictions) +
  aes(x = factor(x), y = predicted, fill = formatted_species) +  # Use new formatted column
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black") +  # Stacked bar plot
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("IR.contemporary", "IR.historical")) +  # Custom x-axis labels
  labs(x = 'Sampling period', y = 'Proportion of predicted probabilities', fill = 'Species') +  # Adjust labels
  theme_classic(base_size = 22) +
  ylim(c(0, 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = scales::hue_pal()(length(species_labels)), labels = species_labels) # Custom fill with labels and original colors

g

and I have this image

I have modified the code to have clear labels indicated with repel:
###function to stack the repels (thank you genius!!): https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/161

position_stack_and_nudge <- function(x = 0, y = 0, vjust = 1, reverse = FALSE) {
  ggproto(NULL, PositionStackAndNudge,
          x = x,
          y = y,
          vjust = vjust,
          reverse = reverse
  )
}

#' @rdname ggplot2-ggproto
#' @format NULL
#' @usage NULL
#' @noRd
PositionStackAndNudge <- ggproto("PositionStackAndNudge", PositionStack,
                                 x = 0,
                                 y = 0,
                                 
                                 setup_params = function(self, data) {
                                   c(
                                     list(x = self$x, y = self$y),
                                     ggproto_parent(PositionStack, self)$setup_params(data)
                                   )
                                 },
                                 
                                 compute_layer = function(self, data, params, panel) {
                                   # operate on the stacked positions (updated in August 2020)
                                   data = ggproto_parent(PositionStack, self)$compute_layer(data, params, panel)
                                   
                                   x_orig <- data$x
                                   y_orig <- data$y
                                   # transform only the dimensions for which non-zero nudging is requested
                                   if (any(params$x != 0)) {
                                     if (any(params$y != 0)) {
                                       data <- transform_position(data, function(x) x + params$x, function(y) y + params$y)
                                     } else {
                                       data <- transform_position(data, function(x) x + params$x, NULL)
                                     }
                                   } else if (any(params$y != 0)) {
                                     data <- transform_position(data, function(x) x, function(y) y + params$y)
                                   }
                                   data$nudge_x <- data$x
                                   data$nudge_y <- data$y
                                   data$x <- x_orig
                                   data$y <- y_orig
                                   
                                   data
                                 },
                                 
                                 compute_panel = function(self, data, params, scales) {
                                   ggproto_parent(PositionStack, self)$compute_panel(data, params, scales)
                                 }
)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# Create dummy entries for spacing
dummy_row_1 <- data.frame(
  x = 1.5,  # Position for the first dummy row (between 1 and 2)
  predicted = 0,  # Height for the dummy bar
  response.level = " "  # Empty space to avoid NA
)

dummy_row_2 <- data.frame(
  x = 3.5,  # Position for the second dummy row (after the last bar)
  predicted = 0,  # Height for the dummy bar
  response.level = " "  # Empty space to avoid NA
)

# Combine the original predictions with the dummy rows
predictions_with_dummy <- bind_rows(predictions, dummy_row_1, dummy_row_2)

# Ensure the x factor levels include the dummies
predictions_with_dummy$x <- factor(predictions_with_dummy$x,
                                   levels = c(1, 1.5, 2, 3.5),  # Use 1.5 and 3.5 for spacing
                                   labels = c("IR.contemporary", "", "IR.historical", ""))  # Correct labels

# Plot
g <- ggplot(predictions_with_dummy) +
  aes(x = x, y = predicted, fill = response.level) +  # Use factor for x-axis
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", color = "black", width = 0.8) +  # Adjust the bar width
  labs(x = 'Sampling period', y = 'Proportion of predicted probabilities', fill = 'Species') +  # Adjust labels
  theme_classic(base_size = 22) +
  ylim(c(0, 1)) + 
  
  # Expand scale to create more space on the right side
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.3, 1.1))) +  # Add space only on the right side
  
  geom_text_repel(data = predictions_with_dummy[!predictions_with_dummy$response.level == " ", ],  # Filter out the dummy rows
                  aes(label = response.level, color = response.level), size = 5, 
                  segment.color = "grey50",  # Color for the segments
                  position = position_stack_and_nudge(vjust = 0.5, y = 0, x = 0.5), direction="y", hjust=0,segment.curvature = 0,segment.ncp = 10,
                  box.padding = 0, max.overlaps = Inf) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())

g


Which leads to this plot that I am in general quite happy with:

I am not unfortunately not able to edit the species labels in the same way as before... any advise how I could achieve what I would like? predict is the result of ggeffect function on my model. Even if I change the original names already before the modelling I would need to manipulate some in italics and some not, so not sure if that would be helpful at all... Any advise would be much appreciated.
predictions would look like:
dput(predictions)
structure(list(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), predicted = c(0.00346765946431063, 0.0253006784802539, 
0.00996429315469765, 0.11818939096279, 0.0187208625272109, 0.0211578581239299, 
0.0166134186519834, 0.419634728462347, 0.0594968082789304, 0.173688828121586, 
2.48311604482499e-05, 0.00392479550225181, 0.00673403374035583, 
0.032324891612091, 0.00783371889201961, 4.65453177468661e-05, 
2.34819092133031e-05, 4.62975512201524e-05, 1.74787489722494e-06, 
0.0828051302117163, 0.000393703313081224, 0.0143522708149105, 
0.0126459538519946, 0.000134307916708042, 0.0308081207014834, 
4.70586119587709e-06, 0.01203074223696, 0.713903150506441, 0.00241769426327644, 
0.0322541735970322, 9.95537535203168e-05, 0.0276224061323732, 
0.000277793521964922, 0.0470972742508751, 0.0178147466657041, 
1.49485513384722e-05, 0.000820741632441746, 0.0494941055141075, 
0.000175689203373736, 0.0376379177112181), response.level = c("Eledone.cirrhosa", 
"Merluccius.merluccius", "Clupea.harengus", "Trisopterus.esmarkii", 
"Sprattus.sprattus", "Teuthida.UKN", "Todaropsis.eblanae", "Trisopterus.sp.", 
"Gobiidae.UKN", "Merlangius.merlangus", "Loligo.sp.", "Fish.UKN", 
"Trachurus.trachurus", "Gadidae.UKN", "Micromesistius.poutassou", 
"Melanogrammus.aeglefinus", "Argentina.sp.", "Sepiolidae.UKN", 
"Alloteuthis.sp.", "Other", "Eledone.cirrhosa", "Merluccius.merluccius", 
"Clupea.harengus", "Trisopterus.esmarkii", "Sprattus.sprattus", 
"Teuthida.UKN", "Todaropsis.eblanae", "Trisopterus.sp.", "Gobiidae.UKN", 
"Merlangius.merlangus", "Loligo.sp.", "Fish.UKN", "Trachurus.trachurus", 
"Gadidae.UKN", "Micromesistius.poutassou", "Melanogrammus.aeglefinus", 
"Argentina.sp.", "Sepiolidae.UKN", "Alloteuthis.sp.", "Other"
), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "1", class = "factor"), 
    y_position = c(0.00173382973215531, 0.0161179987044376, 0.0337504845219133, 
    0.097827326580657, 0.166282453325657, 0.186221813651228, 
    0.205107452039184, 0.42323152559635, 0.662797293966988, 0.779390112167247, 
    0.866246941808264, 0.868221755139614, 0.873551169760918, 
    0.893080632437141, 0.913159937689196, 0.917100069794079, 
    0.91713508340756, 0.917169973137776, 0.917193995850835, 0.958597434894142, 
    0.000196851656540612, 0.00756983872053646, 0.021068951053989, 
    0.0274590819383403, 0.0429302962474361, 0.0583367095287757, 
    0.0643544335778536, 0.427321379949554, 0.785481802334412, 
    0.802817736264567, 0.818994599939843, 0.83285557988279, 0.846805679709959, 
    0.870493213596379, 0.902949224054668, 0.91186407166319, 0.91228191675508, 
    0.937439340328355, 0.962274237687095, 0.981181041144391), 
    cumulative = c(0.00346765946431063, 0.0287683379445645, 0.0387326310992622, 
    0.156922022062052, 0.175642884589263, 0.196800742713193, 
    0.213414161365176, 0.633048889827523, 0.692545698106454, 
    0.86623452622804, 0.866259357388488, 0.87018415289074, 0.876918186631096, 
    0.909243078243187, 0.917076797135206, 0.917123342452953, 
    0.917146824362166, 0.917193121913386, 0.917194869788284, 
    1, 0.000393703313081224, 0.0147459741279917, 0.0273919279799863, 
    0.0275262358966944, 0.0583343565981777, 0.0583390624593736, 
    0.0703698046963336, 0.784272955202774, 0.786690649466051, 
    0.818944823063083, 0.819044376816603, 0.846666782948976, 
    0.846944576470941, 0.894041850721816, 0.91185659738752, 0.911871545938859, 
    0.912692287571301, 0.962186393085408, 0.962362082288782, 
    1), formatted_species = structure(c(4L, 11L, 3L, 19L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 20L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 18L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 14L, 
    1L, 13L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 19L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 
    5L, 18L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 13L), levels = c("Alloteuthis.sp.", 
    "Argentina.sp.", "Clupea.harengus", "Eledone.cirrhosa", "Fish.UKN", 
    "Gadidae.UKN", "Gobiidae.UKN", "Loligo.sp.", "Melanogrammus.aeglefinus", 
    "Merlangius.merlangus", "Merluccius.merluccius", "Micromesistius.poutassou", 
    "Other", "Sepiolidae.UKN", "Sprattus.sprattus", "Teuthida.UKN", 
    "Todaropsis.eblanae", "Trachurus.trachurus", "Trisopterus.esmarkii", 
    "Trisopterus.sp."), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    x = c(1, 2), .rows = structure(list(1:20, 21:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))


Make a column in your data.frame with the names in italics (but not the function expression), and then use parse = TRUE in the geom_repel_text
